# segment tree range minimum query

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, segment-tree, rmq

I am trying to understand segment trees. This is a [great tutorial](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segment-tree-set-1-range-minimum-query/) that shows how to find a minimum in range. However, it is said there that "All levels of the constructed segment tree will be completely filled except the last level. Also, the tree will be a Full Binary Tree because we always divide segments in two halves at every level.". I do not understand how adding is performed? For example, if we add two more elements 6 and 10 - where should they go? Into the right subtree? If yes, there will be 5 not very balanced and halves are not equal. Should I somehow reorder the tree and do computations again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This implementation of a segment tree does not support add operation, so it is not possible to add a new element.

Comment: Can you give an example what implementation support add operation?

Comment: You can use balanced binary search tree to store segment tree's nodes to make adding new elements possible.

Comment: But when balancing you will have to recompute distances, which is not very efficient.

Comment: Recomputation is required only for those nodes that are rotated or are on the path from the root to a new leaf. There are only `O(log N)` such nodes.